# Does the phrasal verb”go off” have a meaning of “give birth”?

Tags: meaning

Does the phrasal verb "go off" have "give birth" as one of its meanings?

I found this meaning in an English-Japanese dictionary that is available online. In the dictionary, only the meaning "give birth" is written as one of the meanings of "go off". There’s no example sentence on it.

Does anyone know how to use "go off" with the meaning "give birth"?

Comment: This question would benefit from some explanation of what led you to think it might have that meaning, as well as what research you've done so far.

Comment: I found this meaning in an English-Japanese dictionary that is available online.

Comment: Hi, Miki. If you can link to the online dictionary, and maybe include some relevant text, that would help us out (and get your question re-opened). You can edit your question by clicking on the "edit" link right underneath it (should be just under the tag "meaning" and to the right of the up/down arrows). You may also want to check out our [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about EL&U, or have a look at our sister site, [English Language Learners.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Welcome, and good luck!

Comment: If you found the definition from a dictionary online, then you should post its link. I think you made a mistake, or misread it. But if you haven't then the question can be reopened. Ping me (@+ username) when you find the link!

Comment: The dictionary is an English-Japanese one,so the definition is written in Japanese.That’s why I thought I didn’t have to post the link.

Answer (score 0):

Not in my experience. Like many prepositional verbs, *go off* has a range of meanings including "go bad" and "explode like a bomb when detonated". This latter would be very suitable as a metaphor if you wished to give the sense of a pregnant woman being like a ticking time bomb, that is "going to undergo sudden change in the future but you don't know exactly when".

Comment: Not to mention all those [*pregnant women who **go off sex**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pregnant+women%22+%22go+off+sex%22) :)